# how to rename webspace with Plesk API RPC?

Tags: api, plesk

As following documentation shows, a filter for a specific webspace-id is possible:
http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.1.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/index.htm?fileName=60842.htm

And it should also be possible to update the name (and hopefully the associated domain) with a "set" call, combined with a gen_setup node:
http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.1.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/index.htm?fileName=60842.htm

Logically tied together in my mind, i come out with following request xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<packet version="1.6.3.0">
  <webspace>
    <set>
      <filter>
        <id>114</id>
      </filter>
      <values>
        <gen_setup>
          <name>testing.com</name>
        </gen_setup>
      </values>
    </set>
  </webspace>
</packet>
```

but the server returns immediately "false"... so, how is it possible to only update the name of a webspace with plesk api rpc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok two things, you can only filter against fields that are known by gen_setup (so, id is not working, take name for example), and you have to include in every case the owner-id field in the gen_setup, even if you don't want to change that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<packet version="1.6.3.0">
  <webspace>
    <set>
      <filter>
        <name>testing.ch</name>
      </filter>
      <values>
        <gen_setup>
          <name>testing.com</name>
          <owner-id>1</owner-id>
        </gen_setup>
      </values>
    </set>
  </webspace>
</packet>
```